# Does injectivity of Type product make sense?

Tags: coq, dependent-type

How to prove the following in Coq?

```
Goal forall (A B : Type), (A*A = B*B)%type -> A = B.
```

If it is not provable, can it be safely added as an axiom?

Comment: My guess is it's safe to assume the axiom, but it's never necessary, you can always reformulate things so you don't need it, which may take more effort however.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia I arrive at this goal while solving [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59439015/rewriting-with-john-majors-equality) question. Do you see a way to avoid it?

Comment: I would switch `JMeq` with a type-specific equivalence relation `eqR (r1 r2 : R A) : Prop := (val _ r1 = val _ r2)` (generalize even more by parameterizing by the equivalence relation on `A`). Then you can reformulate the theorem so it holds by definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes my comment was on the stronger statement. Squaring should be injective but I am not sure wether you can prove this in HoTt.

Comment: This sounds like the best answer up to now.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: The following answer assumes a stronger statement than that in the question: `forall (A B C D : Type), (A*B = C*D)%type -> A = C`. So the answer doesn't actually answer the question.

Your goal is not provable since it contradicts [univalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Univalence_axiom#The_univalence_axiom), which is independent of Coq. The contradiction arises because `A * False` is isomorphic to `False` for any `A`. Univalence then implies `A * False = False` and your goal lets us conclude `A = B` for any `A` and `B`. In particular, `True = False`, which yields a proof of `False` by transport. So, if your goal was provable, Coq would be anti-univalent.

I don't know whether your goal without univalence also leads to a contradiction.

Comment: I am not sure I can see how `A*False = False` lets us conclude `A = B` for any `A` and `B`. Can you elaborate? (Eg the worry then is it should be unsafe to add as an axiom, too?..)

Comment: @SassaNF you're right, I assumed a stronger statement in my proof than was given in the question. Thank you for pointing this out. I've edited the answer accordingly. OP, please unaccept the answer since it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

It is certainly inconsistent with univalence, e.g. 2x3 = 1 x 6 but 1 /= 2 and 3 /= 6. Strange idea to want this.

Comment: But 2, 3, 1 and 6 are not of type Type. Moreover on `nat`, my statement would be something like `forall (x y : nat), x * x = y * y -> x = y`, thus your counterexample does not apply. Could you please provide a proof that my statement is inconsistent with univalence?

Comment: By the way, the (strange?) reason I want this is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59492678/rewriting-with-john-majors-equality/59493958#59493958) by @AndrásKovács

Comment: I am just writing n for the type with n elements. If you have defined Fin then this is just Fin n.

Comment: I see. But in my statement the operands of each product are equal. Restricted to `Fin`types it becomes: `forall (x y : nat), Fin x * Fin x = Fin y * Fin y -> Fin x = Fin y`. So your counterexample does not apply.

Comment: In HoTT you can prove injectivity of squaring easily: that is given A x A = B x B then A = B. The point is that A = { x : A x A | fst x = snd x } where we use Sigma-type to represent subset comprehension, but now { x : A x A | fst x = snd x } = { x : B x B | fst x = snd x} = B. Actually I am glossing over some details (you have to eliminate a pesky transport but in the end this is correct). Hence this should be provable in cubical agda, I don't have the time just now to check this.